# List View data not populating in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am populating list view data using Rest API (parsing JSON) by making use of Custom tabs/View Pager with Fragments,I have debugged code by putting Toast ,data is populated in list but i guess layout is the issue.Someone please guide(Once this is working,will implement Swipe down refresh functionality):-

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_item1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/urlToImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />


    <Button
        android:text="Read More.."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_loadMore"
        android:layout_below="@+id/url"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.amk.myfirstapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/text_json"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Item1(),"Item1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Item2(),"Item2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

TabsPagerAdapter.java

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Item1.java

```
public class Item1  extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsList = new ArrayList<>();

    //private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    AssetManager assetManager;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    String line=null;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context myContext;

    public Item1(){ }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Calling onRefresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            assetManager = this.getActivity().getAssets();
            inputStream = assetManager.open("RestEndPoints.txt");
            isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            input= new BufferedReader(isr);

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
            }
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "List"+list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (String url : list) {
                new Item1.MyAsyncTask().execute(url);
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Got exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        onRefresh();


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item1, container,false);
    }


    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            return RestService.doGet(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if(RetainData.reuseArray == null)
                RetainData.reuseArray = new ArrayList<>();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Entering Json loop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray articles = (JSONArray) json.get("articles");

                for (int i=0;i< articles.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = (JSONObject) articles.get(i);
                    String author = c.getString("author");
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String description = c.getString("description");
                    String url = c.getString("url");
                    String urlToImage = c.getString("urlToImage");
                    String publishedAt = c.getString("publishedAt");

                    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                    hm.put("author",author);
                    hm.put("title",title);
                    hm.put("description",description);
                    hm.put("url",url);
                    hm.put("urlToImage",urlToImage);
                    hm.put("publishedAt",publishedAt);

                    newsList.add(hm);

                    RetainData.reuseArray.add(new com.example.amk.myfirstapplication.ItemList(author, title, description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt));
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Size:"+newsList.size() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                com.example.amk.myfirstapplication.CustomAdapter adapter = new com.example.amk.myfirstapplication.CustomAdapter(myContext,RetainData.reuseArray);

                ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_json);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+RetainData.reuseArray.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<com.example.amk.myfirstapplication.ItemList>{

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<ItemList> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        final com.example.amk.myfirstapplication.ItemList item = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_main, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        //TextView authorName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        TextView titleName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView descriptionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        ImageView urlToImageName = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(urlToImage);

        Button readMore = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_loadMore);
        //TextView publishedAtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.publishedAt);

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        //authorName.setText(item.author);
        titleName.setText(item.title);
        descriptionName.setText(item.description);
        readMore.setTag(item.url);

        readMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(mContext, (String)v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                /*builder.setCloseButtonIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back));*/
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();

                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(mContext, Uri.parse(item.url));
            }
        });


        Glide.with(convertView.getContext())
                .load(item.urlToImage)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .override(600,200)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.android_logo)
                .crossFade()
                .into(urlToImageName);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   activity_main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.vimesh.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout   
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/content_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:context="com.example.vimesh.myapplication.MainActivity"
     tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

first_fragment.xml

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>
```

The ViewPager is the widget that allows the user to swipe left or 
       right  to   see an entirely new screen.Each screen that the ViewPager 
       allows the user to scroll to is really a Fragment.in your example you
       added listview under the ViewPager so when you call each fragment it
        will override the listview.So Add the list view in one of the
       fragment..add viewpager in content_main.xml file....hope it will work

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked.Posting my full code below :-

Answer (score 0):

This might be old but it might help someone.
when building a multitab app with list data, these are the things to ensure that you follow. Your code is not complete but ill explain everything here.

**first**: populating the tabs on the viewpager is different from the list data and you have done it well

```
adapter.addFragment(new Item2(),"Item2");
```

**second**: populating data will be done in the fragments and not in the mainactivity. go to the Item2.java and add your code like this:

```
public Item2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//your code here
    }
```

while running your app, ensure that you get the ids first, populate the list and lastly bind your listview with the adapter. most people forget that

```
theList.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

In the fragment, you are required to return a view as the last piece of code otherwise your app will crash.